# comparing values in files in java for different files

Tags: java, text-files

In Java, If I have a value for a variable in a huge file, and I want to compare that variables value to its value in other files quickly, whats the best way to do this? The first file potentially has over a million unique variables that I would want to compare to the values in the other files. There also can be a lot of comparison files.

Details about the file:
The files store values for different variables at different time slices and contain several million records and potentially millions of unique variables.

Format
Variable,         Value A for Variable,       Value B for Variable,   Value C for Variable
id 1,                some value,                  some value,               some value
id 2,                some value,                  some value,               some value
id 3,                some value,                  some value,               some value
.
.
.
id 3000000,        some value,                  some value,               some value

I have to do statistics on the Values  for A, B, C. I think I can hold the results in an object for one time slice, but not the others, so should I write to a file and read again? Also there could be many time slices.

Comment: Traverse the files first and then store the values somewhere(say ArrayList, Map depending on your need) and then compare the ArrayList\Map values.

Comment: you need to elaborate more, your question does not really clarify what you want and in which format the data is serialized in those files, in short you'd want to read the fies and then perform the comparison in memory.

Comment: you could use `grep` for that which is not Java, but might save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is short on many important details, but I'm assuming that you are talking about files consisting of name-value pairs in some format, and that a given name appears at most once in each file.

This lends itself to the classic sort-merge approach:

1. Sort all files based on the names.
2. Pick 2 files to be compared:
3. Read the name/value pairs from the 2 files in parallel:

   - when names are equal, compare the corresponding values, then skip both pairs
   - when the names are not equal, skip the pair that has the smaller name, and read the next one from that file.
4. Stop when you reach the end of either file.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainframe_sort_merge

---

Note: If you have of the order of a few million records, you should be able to do the sorting and merging in memory ... on a current generation home PC.  If you have billions of records, you will need to use a sort algorithm that splits each (large) input file into subfiles, sorts each subfile, and then merges the result.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Java-Properties File. [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

It manages such Key-Value pairs quite nice.